# Expected identifier but got 'memory'

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract test{
    uint8[] memory lol;
}
```

I am new to solidity and i want to create dynamic array in memory but i always get this error `Expected identifier but got 'memory'`

Please help

Comment: You never define memory arrays in the contract storage. You have to remove the `memory` modifier and replace it with a visibility modifier, such as `public`, `internal`, or `private`.

Comment: "You never define memory arrays in the contract storage" can you explain why please

Comment: That's by design. Memory is allocated to function executions. Storage is allocated to the variables defined at the top of the contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just can't place a dynamic array in memory, it's not allowed

EDIT : nevermind, i missunderstood, this is wrong, sorry

Comment: put i when i moved the same variable in a function it worked

Answer (score 0):

## I had a similar issue but I could solve it after digging into the code more

I declare and used the variable in function scope; Not at contract level or scope.

You could do it also in the contract's constructor and the code will compile.

delete the '-' line and add '+' lines

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

  contract test {

 -  uint8[] memory lol;

 + constructor () {
 +    uint8[] memory lol;
 + }

}
```

Note that if you are not using 'lol' within the constructor, this initialization must be done within the function where you intend to use 'lol'

Comment: Declaring it inside the constructor will scope the variable only within the constructor function. OP wants to make a global variable, so the right answer would be to declare it as storage (default) and not memory. `uint8[] lol;`

Answer (score 0):

The `memory` keyword indicates that the array is being stored in the temporary memory space that's only accessible during the execution of a function and is cleared once the function finishes executing.In Solidity, storage variables are used to persist data on the blockchain across function calls and transactions. You can't directly initialize a dynamic array like this in storage at the point of declaration. To create a dynamic array in storage, you usually need to split the declaration and initialization into two steps. Here's an example of how you can do that:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract test {
    uint8[] public lol;
    constructor() {
    lol.push(..);
    lol.push(..);
  }
}
```